# opening and closing a window programmatically in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit

I have two nibs in my project. I have been digging around the interwebs to figure out how to make a button close or hide the nib that the button is on and open another one. The other nib would have a button that does the same thing but in vice versa.

I don't have the faintest idea where to start with this. IF someone could just make a sample class and methods for this i might have something to work with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Remove window from the screen**

`[window close];`

---

**Hide the window (doesn't release it)**

```
[window orderOut:self];
```

---

**Move the window to the front of its level in the screen list (= show window)**

```
[window orderFront:self];
```

Check out

- [NSWindow Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Window Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000031i)

Comment: Worked beautifully with my classes. I had to make an app controller class that creates an instance of my window controller class, and have the window controller class be the second window's file owner.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to accep the answer if it did help you out